# The [maintenance] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I believe the tag [maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) should be burninated.

It fails all the preliminary checks before burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

**No**, it requires other qualifying tags and question body to establish the necessary context. It is essentially a meta tag — it describes what the OP *wants* to achieve do as opposed to what programming (or software development) problem they are solving. By virtue of being an umbrella term for various activities, it is also ambiguous (see the context section for examples).

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

**No**, "keeping software / hardware functional" describes a *goal* that involves a vast range of activities not necessarily related to programming (example [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1625964) for questions *closed* as off-topic, many more have fallen through the cracks).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**No**, it doesn't qualify the post — only insofar as hinting that the OP is performing *some* sort of maintenance, which is irrelevant to the actual *task* (problem) they are attempting to address.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

**No**, as it describes a goal, it can mean any number of unrelated activities (linked searches are non-exhaustive):

- [Database maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D%20closed%3Ano%20%5Bsql-server%5D&searchOn=3)
- [Git maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D%20closed%3Ano%20%5Bgit%5D&searchOn=3)
- [Legacy codebase maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D%20closed%3Ano%20%5Blegacy-code%5D&searchOn=3)
- [Release management](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D%20closed%3Ano%20%5Brelease-management%5D&searchOn=3)
- [Server maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D%20closed%3Ano%20%5Bnginx%5D&searchOn=3)

The list goes on.

---

It is also problematic because:

- it doesn't have a tag wiki, and its [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maintenance/info) doesn't have usage guidance.
- it attracts too broad / opinion-based questions (f.e.: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73237451/11407695), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477706/11407695), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/162805/11407695), and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D%20closed%3Ayes&searchOn=3)).

Comment: Some of these questions are about a single well-defined topic. For example, the [Laravel questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance*%5D+Laravel+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) are almost all about the built in "maintenance mode" (`php artisan down`). This may be true for other techs but I'm not sure if we need a tag ([tag:maintenance-mode] is slightly better).

Comment: @Laurel yeah, the burnination candidate is present on many similar well-defined topics that could use a specific tag instead. Methinks it's a good idea for observations & retag guidance should the proposal reach the next stage.

Comment: Why isn't laravel enough @Laurel? I don't think 12 questions means that the topic is so common that it would benefit from having its own tag.

Comment: @Braiam but artisanal things are [all the rage](https://www.artisanalsoftwarefestival.com/) these days.  Why not [artisanal tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bartisan*%5D&searchOn=3)? ;)

Comment: @DanielWiddis I still can't understand what has that anything to do with software development.

Comment: Maintenance is not a standalone word, it's always maintenance of something, so it need another tag to precise it, it can be software upgrade for example, or it can be about legacy code, inherited code and so on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about applying updates should have the [maintenance-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-mode) tag instead.
- Questions about releasing software should have the [release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management) tag instead.
- For questions on optimising and maintaining codebases, use more specific tags like [refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring), [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization), [code-reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-reuse), [code-duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-duplication), [code-organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-organization). Be wary that such posts are often off-topic to begin with, close them instead.
- Questions about SQL maintenance plan should have the [maintenance-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-plan) tag instead.
- Questions about monitoring a service for issues should have the [health-monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/health-monitoring) tag instead.
- Questions about various VCS should have specific tags instead and / or at least the [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) tag.

## Progress:

The [maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=maintenance),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaintenance%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=419731)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 6):

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Definitely not.

- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

You know, it really is, but it just doesn't get used like that. I found some sample questions talking about code maintenance and write for maintainability, but they didn't have the tag.

- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No it really doesn't. Every time where it appears to, [maintenance-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-mode) is simply better.

- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope!

Burn please.

It looks like most questions that aren't going to be destroyed for being bad questions simply get the tag removed; however there are some exceptions.

- Questions about applying updates should have tag [maintenance-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-mode) instead.
- Questions about release cycles should have tag [release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management)
- Questions about source control workflow are probably close fodder with opinion based as the reason. Finding good questions of this nature would be evidence this should have been a tag cleanup; however I did not find any good questions of this nature, but only bad ones.
- Questions about server maintenance should be closed/deleted unless they are about completely automated server maintenance in which case they remain, and should be tagged with whatever automated solution is in use. If it's homebrew, it probably needs a [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh) or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag (powershell remoting is a thing).
- There's already a [legacy-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy-code) so consider if any codebase maintenance questions belong there. Most that don't are likely to be closed opinion based. I could be surprised here but I doubt a good one could exist that isn't better served by a language tag and the appropriate design tag for the construct under discussion.